# How to find a 2d angle from pitch and yaw?

Tags: opengl, glm-math, euler-angles

In my graphic application, I have an object that represents a fps-like camera. This object contains a pitch, a yaw and a position field. My question is how to move the camera position with a joystick. The joystick give a radian angle as output.

My idea to solve this question was to first find a angle on the y axis from the yaw and pitch of the camera, then add the angle from the joystick, convert this angle to a vector and add the normalized version of this vector to my camera position. I think it would be a good idea, but I don't know how to find a angle on the y axis from pitch and yaw nor how to convert this angle to a vector. Can someone help me.

Image: [Moving the camera with a joystick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4J9W.png)

Answer (score 0):

*"angle on the y axis from the yaw and pitch"*: The **yaw** and **pitch** are the angles of the camera in the respective axes. I believe you want calculate the camera direction; you can calculate your camera direction using some trigonometry with the yaw and pitch.

From what I know:

```
cos(yaw) = x-component of the camera direction
sin(pitch) = y-component of the camera direction
```

****The above equations needs to fact checked on (if someone knows better way, they might edit this answer in the future...)**

And there you have your camera direction. **Make sure to normalise it, because it is a direction vector**. Btw, this [thread](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/56529/154918) seems to answer your question.